# OAuth 2.0 state parameter for csrf protection

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, csrf, csrf-token

I have some questions about the flow the authorization code grant flow.
I know the first part of oauth2 is that send `https://auth.server/oauth2/auth?scope= &redirect_uri=https://app.example.com/oauth2/callback &response_type=code&client_id=123 &state=af0ifjsldkj`

I am confused about the state parameter. I understand that the state parameter is for preventing the attack of csrf. But Where should i save this parameter?  If i save it into the session of auth server, how can i verify the state in the following step?

```
https://app.example.com/oauth2/callback?
code=MsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&state=af0ifjsldkj
```

how can i verify the state parameter in app.example.com , but the state paramter save in the session of auth server?

Answer (score 2):

Your tech stack's security library should manage this for you and the state will be saved within your app:

- For a single page app it is common to save state to local storage
- For a server side web app it is common to use a temporary HTTP only cookie instead

The Auth Server's only job is to ensure that it returns the same state in the response to the app that it received in the request from the app. Any off the shelf Auth Server will do that for you.

Behaviour is summarised visually in [steps 4 and 7 of my blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/). In my case I am using an SPA and the OIDC Client library manages verifying response state.

As a result, my app is protected against CSRF attacks. If someone pasted this into the browser address bar my app would not attempt to process the authorization code:

- [https://web.mycompany.com/spa?code=xxx'&state=yyy](https://web.mycompany.com/spa?code=xxx%27&state=yyy)

Comment: but as you mentioned about the cookie , but why don't we use session?

Comment: The state is meant to be saved in the Client / UI and verified there, according to OAuth standards, to protect against a certain class of substitution attack. In some cases the Auth Server does indeed store state in its session, such as for PKCE protection, though this protects against different attacks. The [OAuth Threat Model](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6819#section-4.4.1.8) discusses these aspects in greater detail.